# Call jax-ws web service from Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web-services

If I am call my `JAX-WS` Web Service, I am getting the following error message at server-side.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler handleExchange
WARNING: Cannot handle HTTP method: OPTIONS
```

My html code is :

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            function call() {
                var side = sideid.value;
                var side1 = sideid1.value;
                var req = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/\" xmlns:web=\"http://core.example.com/\"><soapenv:Body><web:rectangle><length>" + side + "</length><breadth>" + side1 + "</breadth></web:rectangle></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
                //var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                //var reqXML = xmlDoc.loadXML(req);
                var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                xmlDoc.onload = req;
                //var reqXML = xmlDoc.load(req);
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert(xmlhttp.status);
                        var response = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                        // xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
                        //alert(response.selectSingleNode(".//return").text);
                        alert("======" + response);
                    }
                }
                var soapaction = "http://core.example.com/rectangle";
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8090/area?wsdl", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapaction);
                xmlhttp.send(req);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>Side Length:
        <input type="text" id="sideid"></input>Length:
        <input type="text" id="sideid1"></input>
        <button onclick="call();">area of square</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Please give me your comments about how to call a Web Service from Javascript which should work on Mozilla browser.

Comment: Are you sure that the source of your problem is this Javascript code?

Comment: Yeah...i think so...because my webservice is working fine..I have tested it using SOAPUI tool..there am getting response...what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you add your java code?